# Do we need a paid firebase/firestore account to implement stripe payments?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In the tutorial docs of implementing Stripe payments with Angular and Firebase it says in a side note:

"Side Note: You will need a paid Firebase account for this cloud function to work. Firebase blocks external API requests on the free “Spark” plan."

Comment: Your quote answers your question, so what actually is your issue?

Comment: I am trying to confirm, since the docs for the tutorial are from 2017. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-stripe-payments-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-backend/

Comment: So what does the Firebase Spark plan description say about calling external API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling to 3rd party web services from Cloud Functions requires a paid project.

You can check this in the [Firebase documentation on setting up Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize):

> Firebase projects on the Spark plan can make only outbound requests to Google APIs. Requests to third-party APIs fail with an error. For more information about upgrading your project, see [Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

And in the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/):

> The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services.

And in some of the previous questions on the same topic:

- [Error connecting to Stripe from Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447966/error-connecting-to-stripe-from-firebase-cloud-function)
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured)