# DialogFlow Fulfillment

Tags: json, rss, dialogflow-es

I want to add a the library [rss-to-json](https://github.com/nasa8x/rss-to-json/) to my fulfillment to convert news from a website in rss format to json format. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can treat this just like most other npm managed library.

If you are managing the code on your own machine and then deploying it to some cloud environment (such as firebase cloud functions), then you can install it with `npm` as usual with

```
npm install rss-to-json --save
```

If you're using Dialogflow's inline code editor, then you need to add this manually to the `package.json` file in the editor. To do this,

- Make sure you've selected the "Fulfillment" left navigation and enabled on the inline code editor
- Select the `package.json` tab that is right above the editor
- Scroll the editor down and add the line to the "dependencies" section
- When you're done, make sure you click the "Deploy" button

[image]

You should also make sure that you are using an upgraded [Firebase plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448152/1405634), since the default "Spark" plan can only access servers on Google's network.